# How do I search and replace in vi to eliminate a random number of random characters preceding a known string?

Tags: search, replace, wildcard, vi

I have text files which look like this:

```
0 298047498 /directory1/app/20170417/file1.blob 0 f191
e 6569844 /directory1/app/20170417/file2.blob 0 f191
344 /directory1/app/20170417/file3.blob 0
8946 /directory1/app/20170417/file4.blob 0
196496 /directory1/app/20170417/file5.blob 0
9 182340752 /directory1/app/20170417/file6.blob 0 f191
68802 /directory1/app/20170417/file7.blob 0
```

I want to remove everything prior to the first / and everything after the file extension.

Results should look like this:

```
/directory1/app/20170417/file1.blob
/directory1/app/20170417/file2.blob
/directory1/app/20170417/file3.blob
```

Is there a way to do this using vi search and replace?

Comment: Hi, Stackoverflow is the resource to ask questions about programming. Vi commands are not related to it

Answer (score 0):

This type of question may be better placed here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

But for now:
Yout can e.g. use a simple vim-macro, in which you collect all the key-strokes you need to edit one line and repeat this macro as many times as you need it.

Here are simply the key-strokes for **one line**:

```
dt/WD
```

`d` = delete..
`t` = ..till the first "/"
`W` = [shift]+[w] jumps to the next Word (after the "file-location-string")
`D` = [shift]+[d] deletes till the end of the current line

If you want to **record this as a macro**, do the following, with the keystrokes from above, inbetween - like this:

```
qmdt/WD[home][down]q
```

`qm` = start the recording of a macro in buffer "m"
... key-strokes from above
`[home][down]` = key [home] followed by [arrow down]-key, to move into the next line (for convenince)
`q` = end up the macro-recording

Now **execute that macro** with:

```
@m
```

And if you added the [down] key, you can do something like:

```
7@m
```

with which you fire your macro 7 times, for all your 7 lines.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For people with English keyboards, pos1 is the Home key.